# How to stop DispatchGroup after time? iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm working with `DispatchGroup`, I use this to execute two requests from two different servers. When the response comes from two servers, `DispatchGroup` is called `notify()`, the problem is that one response from the server may not come (it happened once) how can `DispatchGroup` notify itself after some time? Or how can I stop the `DispatchGroup`? I made an example, but I think this is not what I need.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 7.5, repeats: false) { [weak self] (timer) in
        guard let _self = self else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if _self.leaveDispatchGroupDigit == 0 {
                _self.requestGroup.leave()
                _self.requestGroup.leave()
            }
            if _self.leaveDispatchGroupDigit == 1 {
                _self.requestGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think creating a timer is a bad way. How are you performing the requests? You could set a timeout for them, in that way, in the callback you can send some notify event

Comment: I agree. Fix the root problem, that your request is not timing out, rather than contorting yourself to program around the problem.

Comment: @carlos21 Thanks for the advice, so I'll do it.

Comment: Create timeout for the request, not timer for the dispatch

Comment: @Alexsander, I added it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a timeout for the request is the cleanest solution in this case :)